# Make a tkinter window that always hides behind other windows

Tags: tkinter

How can i make a tkinter window hide behind other windows?
should i use

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
while True:
    root.lower()

root.mainloop()
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "hide behind other windows"? Which other windows? What exactly do you want to achieve? Describe better your situation!

Comment: `root.attributes("-topmost", 1)` can be used to put the window on top of the others, but as far as I know, there is no 'behindmost' equivalent. In linux, using Xfce desktop, I can tell the window to be behind all other windows from the right click menu on the window titlebar.

Comment: what's the purpose of being behind all windows that can't be served by simply hiding the window? Also, what do you expect to happen if the user wants to bring it forward by clicking on the window titlebar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer

I used **ctypes** to trigger keystrokes
I triggered **Alt+Esc** to hide the window behind the others